# Find the selected option using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to only get the selected options of a select. For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">2002/12</option>
  <option value="1">2003/12</option>
  <option value="2">2004/12</option>
  <option value="3">2005/12</option>
  <option value="4">2006/12</option>
  <option value="5" selected>2007/12</option>
</select>
```

I know I can do

```
theSelectTag.findAll('option',attrs={'selected':''})
```

but that is returning all the options.  Is there a way to get all the elements where an attribute exists?  Please note, I ask for all, as the site I'm scraping does include the selected attribute for multiple options.

I'm using Python 2.7 and Beautiful Soup 4.1.2

Answer (score 17):

Passing `True` as the attribute's value will match all elements with that attribute:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<select>
...   <option value="0">2002/12</option>
...   <option value="1">2003/12</option>
...   <option value="2">2004/12</option>
...   <option value="3">2005/12</option>
...   <option value="4">2006/12</option>
...   <option value="5" selected>2007/12</option>
... </select>''')
>>> soup.find_all('option', selected=True)
    [<option selected="" value="5">2007/12</option>]
>>> soup.find_all('option', {'selected': True})
    [<option selected="" value="5">2007/12</option>]
```

And with lxml:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.HTML('''<select>
  <option value="0">2002/12</option>
  <option value="1">2003/12</option>
  <option value="2">2004/12</option>
  <option value="3">2005/12</option>
  <option value="4">2006/12</option>
  <option value="5" selected>2007/12</option>
</select>''')
>>> root.xpath('//option[@selected]')
    [<Element option at 0x228b7d0>]
```

Comment: Is there any reason this wouldn't work on my system?  I'm getting an empty set if I try either of your selected arguments. I confirmed that I am getting the whole set if I exclude them. I'm using Python 2.7 and Beautiful Soup 4.1.2

Comment: @EricG: That's odd. Have you tried installing `lxml` and `html5lib`?

Comment: I haven't.  It is primarily working and I can pretty easily work around the issue.  Just thought this should have been doable with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: This doesn't work unless you have either lxml or html5lib installed. BeautifulSoup preferences those parsers before falling back on the built-in. The reason why it works for those parsers, is that they fill in the unspecified attribute value with an empty string - see Blender's example above where the find_all response has the selected attribute as 'selected=""' instead of just 'selected' as in the input HTML. With the built-in parser, the attribute value is left as None which is excluded from matching (http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1575).

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
theSelectTag.select_one('option:checked')
```

and it will return you the only one selected option.