# How to get the option selected using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python3.7 and BeautifulSoup4, im still learning how to scarp using python and BeautifulSoup, i have a page in html and i want to get all option selected in it.

this is my code:

```
ZeroDay = s.post("https://site/Add_Studant.php",data={"SID":123456})
    ZeroDay_content = bs(ZeroDay.content,"html.parser", from_encoding='windows-1256')
    std_ID    = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"SID[]"})["value"]
    std_name  = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"Name[]"})["value"]
    std_major_= ZeroDay_content.select_one("option[selected]", {"name":"Qualifications[]"})["value"]
    std_major = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"Specialization[]"})["value"]
    std_social= ZeroDay_content.select_one("option[selected]", {"name":"MILITARY_STATUS[]"})["value"]
    std_ID_num= ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"ID_Number[]"})["value"]
    std_gender= ZeroDay_content.select_one("option[selected]", {"name":"Gender[]"})["value"]
    print(std_ID,std_name,std_gender,std_major,std_major_,std_ID_num,std_social)
```

after i run the code the result not contain the value of **std_social and std_gender** i think because i used select_one twice but i have search a lot in internet about the solutions all are not worked with my code .

this is how the page looks like in html, first select group:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="Qualifications[]"  style="padding:5px;"><!-- the id is important in validation -->
                      <option value="user" >user</option>
                      <option value="admin" selected> admin</option>
```

the second select group:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="MILITARY_STATUS[]" >
                      <option value="USA" >USA</option>
                      <option value="sy" selected>sy</option>
                      <option value="pal" >pal</option>
                      <option value="jordan" >jordan</option>
```

after i run the code it shows only admin value not as i need **admin and sy**

i have checked these links here but with no result:

> [Find the selected option using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863495/find-the-selected-option-using-beautifulsoup)

> [python BeautifulSoup get select.value not text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392466/python-beautifulsoup-get-select-value-not-text)

> [How to get the option text using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555307/how-to-get-the-option-text-using-beautifulsoup)

> [Scraping the selected value from a dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57046432/scraping-the-selected-value-from-a-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` belongs to the `select`, not the `option`.

```
std_social= ZeroDay_content.select_one("select[name='MILITARY_STATUS[]'] option[selected]")["value"]
```